# Read/download a .doc file on a FTP in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I’m trying to be able to read / download files from a FTP on a frameworkless PHP server (yes). What I implemented is working fine for PDF files : It opens a tab and display them without problem. But I've a problem with `.doc`, `.docx` or `even .odt` files. Using Libre Office, I get a file with unreadable content like : `��R#���X�A9#]��ja��b(�>e��-�8a�1�1,!~k��#��׫�Lލ��j��dl����`. However, I'm sure that the stored file on the FTP server is valid. (I get a readable file if I download it with a FTP client).

Here's how I'm getting my files :

```php
    header("Content-type: $mimeType");
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    
    if (!ftp_get($connexion, "php://output", $filename, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Couldn't read $filename";
    }
    ftp_close($connexion);
```

---

Some informations:

It **works** on a file which is stored **locally**, using

```php
    ob_end_clean();
    readfile($file);
```

. The problem is really happening when I'm using `ftp_get()`.
`$mimeType` is dynamically set according to the file extension. I tried using `FTP_ASCII` mode, I tried using every other php:// flux, I tried setting `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` instead of `binary`... Still the same.

Comment: What happens when you write the received data to a file on your server first, and then you download that afterwards - does that file “work” then?

Comment: Hello, oh, by doing this way it... works! I'll write a solution after some tests to be 100% sure I'll keep this solution. Thanks a lot! Have a good day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [04FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955263/04fs), it works. The funny thing is that my initial way eventually works after trying [04FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955263/04fs)'s solution, by simply clearing the ouptut buffer before ~~.

[04FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955263/04fs)'s suggestion solution :

```php
    $filename = "ftp://".FTP_USER.":".FTP_PASS."@".FTP_HOST."/$filename";
    ob_clean();
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $handle = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    rewind($handle);
    header("Content-type: $mimeType");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '";');
    fpassthru($handle);
    fclose($handle);
```

Then I tried my initial solution with an `ob_clean()` and... It works.

```php
    ob_clean();
    header("Content-type: $mimeType");
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    if (!ftp_get($connexion, "php://output", $filename, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Couldn't read $filename";
    }
    ftp_close($connexion);
```

It wasn't needed for `.pdf` files, but it is for `.doc`, `.docx` etc...